# How to close Objectbox Store and delete data files

Tags: android, objectbox

I'v got an exception after I call `put()` with my data list.
I know that I closed the box before with a reason (deleteAllFiles() must be closed).
How should I open it again? As I see, dataBoxStore is not null after I closed it.

**My code:**

```
dataBoxStore = MyObjectBox.builder().androidContext(this).name("DB").build();

dataBoxStore.close();
dataBoxStore.deleteAllFiles();

final Box<Data> areaLocationBox = dataBoxStore.boxFor(Data.class);
areaLocationBox.put(myList);
```

**Exception:**

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Store is closed
    at io.objectbox.BoxStore.checkOpen(BoxStore.java:261)
    at io.objectbox.BoxStore.beginTx(BoxStore.java:310)
    at io.objectbox.Box.getWriter(Box.java:107)
    at io.objectbox.Box.put(Box.java:389)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With ObjectBox 1.3 this got simpler. You can use [one of the static BoxStore.deleteAllFiles methods](http://objectbox.io/files/objectbox-java/current/io/objectbox/BoxStore.html#deleteAllFiles-java.lang.Object-java.lang.String-) without initiating a BoxStore:

```
BoxStore.deleteAllFiles(context, "DB");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dataBoxStore.put(myList);
```

Throw the exception of Store is closed while and dataBoxStore is not null.

What I found is to initiate the boxStore again to use it:

```
dataBoxStore = MyObjectBox.builder().androidContext(this).name("DB").build();

dataBoxStore.close();
dataBoxStore.deleteAllFiles();

dataBoxStore = MyObjectBox.builder().androidContext(this).name("DB").build();
final Box<Data> areaLocationBox = dataBoxStore.boxFor(Data.class);
areaLocationBox.put(myList);
```

Comment: If someone can find another option to solve it just tell me. but as I see there is no any function to open the boxStore without to initiate it again.

Comment: It is OK. I just realized that the static `deleteAllFiles` method with `File`parameter is not really usable for Android. Will think about that for upcoming 1.2.2 release.

Comment: @MarkusJunginger Great. So can you mark it as the correct answer for now?

Comment: Will be deprecated in hopefully a few hours... :-)

Comment: @MarkusJunginger did it fix? If so please update the answer or please mark it as current answer.

Comment: Done interally, but for the release, we'll have to finish something else first.