# Destroy objectbox DB

Tags: android, kotlin, objectbox

I am currently using objectbox via koin dependency injection within my android app. It works fine however i need to re-initialise my DI and so i need to destroy the boxStore before. This is because i initialise the box via DI and if i do not destroy the current BoxStore I cannot create a new one.

I've found a similar post [How to close Objectbox Store and delete data files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47436861/how-to-close-objectbox-store-and-delete-data-files) however it hasn't solved my issue.

I have tried calling deleteAllFiles however i am getting an error.

```
        BoxStore.deleteAllFiles(context, (BoxStoreBuilder.DEFAULT_NAME))

        BoxStore.deleteAllFiles(context, null)
```

I am getting the error message:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot delete files: store is still open

this is on the line of code mentioned above. Any suggestions would be very helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution:

i had to access each of my boxes individually and delete them one at a time.

```
fun clearAll(){
    firstBox.box.removeAll()
    secondBox.box.removeAll()
    ....... 
}


fun closeAll(){
    firstBox.box.close()
    secondBox.box.close()
    ....... 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just close the boxStore and then delete all files:

```
boxStore.close();
boxStore.deleteAllFiles();
```

There's also a [static method](http://objectbox.io/files/objectbox-java/current/io/objectbox/BoxStore.html#deleteAllFiles-java.lang.Object-java.lang.String-) for deleting all the files ( if you want to delete all files before you open boxStore )

It's the most efficient way.

Ref: https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-java/issues/317

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest a solution. You can get all entity classes and get each box and clear them.

```
boxStore.getAllEntityClasses().forEach( entityClass -> 
   boxStore.boxFor(entityClass
).removeAll());
```